# Unknown login account after changing from Domain to Workgroup

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I have an HP Windows 10 machine that suddenly changed my account and now I can't log in.

The computer was part of a Domain from my previous school and I was getting rid of it, so I changed it from Domain to Workgroup, it required me to restart for the changes to take effect, as soon as it restarted, I noticed a new account by the name of Hp.

When I use the previous password for the domain account, it doesn't go through and there's no option like forgot password or create a new account.

How can I log back in?

**Note:** I didn't have any local user account. (computer only has the Domain account)

Comment: You removed any access to your domain account when you removed it from the domain. You have to setup a local account before you do that. Windows actually warns you of this. If you don’t have the credentials for the local account `hp` then you can’t login. You’ll have to consider reloading the computer from scratch or trying to perform a password reset.

Comment: After you try the last suggestion here, I'd find a way to nicely ask for help from one of the admins of that domain.  I tried to help change over to local account for someone, didn't ask for help, and wasted a day.  Do know however, that a domain user is totally separate from and local USERNAME and PW. -- separate user folders, permissions, etc.  A SUPER-admin local account, lets you move ALL files where needed, using your local user account.  CLUE - "HP"?  I am guessing the PW IS automatically created, and HP, INC. knows the common PW's used, like "admin", or "administrator".  TRY them 1st.

Comment: I upvoted your question... Once you do figure it out precisely how to get out of this mess, or prevent it easily if not:  Please write and provide an "answer" to your own question, (after looking for duplicate similar questions that have great answers.)  You've ID'ed a real severe problem, so although some admins disagree, this needs to be fully understood, which means ALLOWING very similar questions AND answers, to enhance everyone's understanding.  Once you know you have a problem like you were shocked to learn, it's too late to fix it.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know I locked myself out just like that, @Appleoddity don't remember seeing that warning though! I'll surely post an answer as soon I figure this out.

Comment: Try just pushing enter (use a blank password).

Comment: Please see step 7 [here](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-10/unjoin-windows-10-domain/) where you are reminded by Windows that you need to “know the password of the local administrator account to login.”

Comment: Blank doesn't work. Funny enough the closest thing to that I saw was where I was required to know the details of the admin on Domain to apply the changes and as strange as it might sound, on that screen I provided my Domain username and password and it worked! And that's how I locked myself out.

Comment: @Ceelogre No guarantee it will work with Windows 10 (or in this particular instance) but [Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor](https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) might be worth looking at. It has an option to blank passwords that has worked consistently in the past for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a variation of what Harry suggested: Booted from a password reset tool and removed the password from the account.

I was then able to login and create new users.

Comment: Do you have any name of good tool ?

Comment: I don't remember which tool I used but back in the days, spotmau did the job pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a local user account of type administrator.

To do that, you will need to first create a Windows 10 boot USB on another
Windows 10 computer.
See the article
[Create Bootable USB Flash Drive to Install Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html).

Boot off this boot media (may require changing the boot order in the BIOS),
and choose Repair, then Troubleshoot, Advanced options, and finally Command prompt.
For more details see the article
[Open Command Prompt at Boot in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2880-open-command-prompt-boot-windows-10-a.html#option1).

While in the command prompt, create a new administrator account by typing the
following commands (using your preferences for user-name and password):

```
net user NewUserName NewUserPassword /add
net localgroup administrators NewUserName /add
```

Now remove the boot media and you may use this new local account to login.